# Android: How to put out an ImageView of the screen with the finger?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-imageview, ontouchlistener

I'm looking for a way to move an ImageView with the finger (in any direction) and when the ImageView is moved out of the screen this one disappear and then a new one appear in the middle of the screen.

You know thanks to which library I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be an ImageView?

You can draw a Bitmap on canvas and change its coordinates depending on where the user touches then just check if x < 0 or x > canvas.getWidth() or y < 0 or y > canvas.getHeight()

Here's someone else's example of this:
[Touch and drag image in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255859/touch-and-drag-image-in-android)