# Android how to drag edge/side to resize imageview by using picasso library

Tags: android, image, resize, picasso

i manage to do a imageview that allow user drag edge/ side to resize the imageview, currently i select the imageview by using the picasso library, is it possible to implement the drag edge/side to resize the imageview by using picasso library or need to implement it by other library, any suggestion to solve this problem?

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);
    Picasso.with(this)
            .load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png")
            .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder) // optional
            .error(R.drawable.error)         // optional
            .resize(450, 500)               // optional
            .rotate(90)                    // optional
            .into(imageView);

  }
}
```

Comment: dont resize with picasso, just hard code your image view with height and width, and set its scale type fitxy  , when ever user drags the image view programatically increase/decrease its height or width accordingly

Comment: @Redman thanks but how can i detect the user is dragging the edge/side of imageview?

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255859/touch-and-drag-image-in-android

Comment: @Redman i tried the code , how to apply the ballView to the imageView so,  the imageview edge contain 4 ballview?